# TFS build output path - cannot be found by OctoPack to create Nuget package

Tags: tfs, nuget, nuget-package, octopus-deploy

I have a fairly simple class library who's output is a single assembly.
There is a build set up on TFS.

I'm using Octopack in order to package this up as a nuget package.

In my NuSpec file, I specify my `<files>` section like this:

This is to enable OctoPack to place the assembly in the lib folder (otherwise it just puts it in the root of the package, and therefore cannot be referenced from other projects)

The TFS build fails. The relevant parts of the log are below:

```
   CopyFilesToOutputDirectory:
     Copying file from "obj\Debug\Company.NameOfAssembly.dll" to "C:\Builds\4\dotNet\Company.NameOfAssembly\bin\Company.NameOfAssembly.dll".
     Company.NameOfAssembly -> C:\Builds\4\dotNet\Company.NameOfAssembly\bin\Company.NameOfAssembly.dll
     Copying file from "obj\Debug\Company.NameOfAssembly.pdb" to "C:\Builds\4\dotNet\Company.NameOfAssembly\bin\Company.NameOfAssembly.pdb".
   OctoPack:
     OctoPack: Get version info from assembly: C:\Builds\4\dotNet\Company.NameOfAssembly\bin\Company.NameOfAssembly.dll
     Using package version: 1.0.5521.18156
     OctoPack: Written files: 2
     OctoPack: Copy file: C:\Builds\4\dotNet\Company.NameOfAssembly\src\Company.NameOfAssembly\Company.NameOfAssembly.nuspec
     OctoPack: Files will not be added because the NuSpec file already contains a <files /> section with one or more elements and option OctoPackEnforceAddingFiles was not specified.
     OctoPack: Attempting to build package from 'Company.NameOfAssembly.nuspec'.
 1>MSBUILD : OctoPack error OCTONUGET: Cannot create a package that has no dependencies nor content. [C:\Builds\4\dotNet\Company.NameOfAssembly\src\Company.NameOfAssembly\Company.NameOfAssembly.csproj]
```

It's basically because it can't find the files in 'bin' folder, as specified in my NuSpec -
Is there a way I can specify 'C:\Builds\4\dotNet\Company.NameOfAssembly\bin' in my files src?

Comment: If you are using a recent version of TFS you can try to set the output location in the build section of the template to AsConfigured.  That will disable the behavior of the template that overrides OutDir on the MSbuild command line so it builds like it does in VS or the normal command line.  Then you can add a post-build script that copies what you want from their locations under TB_BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY to TF_BUILD_BINARIESDIRECTORY so they are dropped.

Comment: @Alex I'm having the same issue. If you have found a solution, can you please share it?

Comment: @Baga this was 9 months ago, I'm no longer working on this project, I don't remember it being fixed. The upvoted answer below is the most likely though

Comment: @Alex Ok will try it, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be the dot in one of your folders, and it's a NuGet issue rather than  one with OctoPack. The [workaround suggested here](https://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/2111) - using NuGet's `-NoDefaultExcludes` switch works for me (I recently came across the same problem).

With OctoPack you can specify it using the `OctoPackNuGetArguments` paramter, see [here, where `-NoDefaultExcludes` is even used as an example](http://docs.octopusdeploy.com/display/OD/Using+OctoPack) !

Comment: Most issues with the OctoPack are really NuGet problems in disguise.

Comment: Google Chrome is warning me about that codeplex link you posted. Says there's malicous code on the page

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the  section and let OctoPack do the work.

P.s. Never use files in the "obj" folders...

Comment: unfortunately that's not gonna work - by 'letting octopack do the work' it doesn't put the outputted assemblies in the lib folder in the nuget package

Comment: That's because OctoPack is for deploying applications and not for component. You should use OOB NuGet to do the package.

Answer (score 0):

I think [mthierba](https://stackoverflow.com/users/736263/mthierba) is right; try leveraging some of the parameters the OctoPack provides. Most (if not *all*) of my OctoPack issues were really NuGet problems.

I'd also add that it's probably easier to try doing builds locally and customizing your NuSpec as you desire, rather than going through the hassle of constant builds on TFS and waiting for the final results. Local NuSpec customization is an effective time saver.